# Tikz Forest label positioning

Tags: labels, tikz-trees, forest

I'm constructing a tree diagram using the `forest` package, and I want to label the edges.
Usually, Tikz is quite good at avoiding a collision between the label and the edge, but if the branches of my tree are forced to spread out too much then the label starts to overlap the edge.

Is there a way of manually offsetting the labels I've added?
Or perhaps there is a way of getting the labels to interrupt the edge, much like the `description` option for labels in tikzcd?

[image: Tree diagram with bad edge label positioning]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow'=north}
  [A
    [B, edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{1}} [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []]
    [C, edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{2}} [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: try `yshift=` and some dimension in the nodes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `auto` instead of `left:

[image]

Or use `above`:

[image]

Or `below`

[image]

There is also `above left` `above right` `below right` `above=2mm` `below=1cm` etc. Choose whatever you like.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow'=north}
  [A
    [B, edge label={node[midway,below,font=\scriptsize]{1}} [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []]
    [C, edge label={node[midway,below,font=\scriptsize]{2}} [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

If you want the labels to interrupt the edges, remove `left` or whatever you are using and use `fill=white`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow'=north}
  [A
    [B, edge label={node[midway,fill=white,font=\scriptsize]{1}} [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []]
    [C, edge label={node[midway,fill=white,font=\scriptsize]{2}} [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\edge label={node[xshift=5mm, yshift=8mm]{TEXT}}` for random position

Comment: in case of `right` `below` `above` `left` the node spins around a point that it at the top of the branch. In case of `midway` it is in the middle of the branch.
What about putting the label in the bottom of the branch? e.g., near A.

Comment: @FiboKowalsky: Actually `A` itself is a node. So you can label it and use it as an anchor to put a new node below it.

Answer (score 7):

This is an addendum to [Harish Kumar's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236506/).

If you want the same positioning for the edge labels for the whole tree, you can put the specification for the creation of the labels in `for tree` at the start, and then just write `edge label=1`, `edge label=2` etc. in the tree itself. For example, suppose that you wanted the labels `above` the edges. Then you could use the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=north,
    delay={
      edge label/.wrap value={node[midway, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, above]{#1}},
    },
    font=\sffamily,
  }
  [A
  [B, edge label=1 [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []]
    [C, edge label=2 [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: edge labels with less typing]

If you want the flexibility of specifying different positions, you can set up a style, `my edge label`, which takes two arguments: the first is the required position and the second the label content. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\forestset{
  my edge label/.style 2 args={
    edge label={node[midway, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, #1]{#2}},
  },
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=north,
    font=\sffamily,
  }
  [A
  [B, my edge label={below}{1} [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []]
    [C, my edge label={above}{2} [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: flexible edge labels with less typing]