# tikz unruly tree

Tags: tikz-trees

Please forgive the very specific question that may not help many others.  I need a kind of decision tree drawn.  I am struggling with control.

I started with a dot (graphviz) tree.  After a lot of tinkering, I got it almost to where I wanted it to be...

[image: unruly tree in graphviz dot]

except that a bug in graphviz messes up the placement of the arrows on the far right going into the cascade box: C3R4 should be between C3R3 and C3R5, not above C3R1.  (C2R1 should be higher up, too.)  [please ignore box color.]  graphviz was so close, but no cigar.

after experimenting with converting it into tikz via `dot2tex`, I gave up and decided to go native with tikz instead.

as usual, I tried to find a similar example on the web and modify it.  my best result was

```
\documentclass[border=30pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, align=center,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
  root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30},
  fancy/.style    = {circle,draw},
  prect/.style    = {rectangle,draw},
  dot/.style      = {draw},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    grow                    = right,
    sibling distance        = 10em,
    level distance          = 10em,
    edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
    % every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
    sloped  %% for the labels, according to angle of link
  ]

  \node [root] {START}
  child {
    node [fancy] {R11}
    edge from parent node [below] {$\ell1$}
  }
    % 
  child {
    node [fancy] {A11}
    child {
      node [prect] {coin}
      child {
        node [fancy] {R33}
        child { node {A4L5} } % edge from parent node [above] {$h2XA5$}
        child { node {A4L6} } % edge from parent node [above] {$h2XA6$}
        edge from parent node [below] {1/2}
      }
      child {
        node [fancy] {A32}
        child {
          node {A4X1} } % edge from parent node [above] {$h35$}
        child {
          node {A4X2} }  % edge from parent node [above] {$h36$}
        edge from parent node [above] {1/2}
      }
      edge from parent node [below] {$\ell2$}
    }
%
    child {
      node [dot] {}
      child {
        node [fancy] {A31}
        child { node {A41}  }
        child { node {A42} }
      }
      edge from parent node [above] {h2}
    }
    edge from parent node [above] {$h1$}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

this got me to

[image: unruly tree attempt in tikz]

not even a cigarette now

1. I need the little rectangle between C1R1 and C2R1 to disappear (and C2R1 needs to remain above C2R2);
2. I need C2R1 to be higher up (and still link to C3R1 and C3R2);
3. I need C2R2 to continue to link to C3R3 and C3R4 nearby;
4. I obviously don't want C3R6 and C3R4 to share a slot.
5. I have not even gotten to attempting to draw the dashed box with text around C3R1 through C3R4.

I tried `sibling angle=xx` on some child nodes, but this seemed to be ignored.  (level distance worked.)  I also have not gotten to visual fine-tuning yet, which sibling angle and level distance could help with.

**Nuisance**: how do replace the circles with (fatter) ovals?

advice highly appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach using `tikz`

[image: tikz tree v02]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{makecell}

\tikzset{%
    every node/.style={font=\small},
}
\tikzstyle{arrowline}=[-latex, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]
\tikzstyle{elor}=[ellipse, minimum width=20pt, minimum height=10pt, fill=orange!50!red!50!white]
\tikzstyle{elwh}=[draw, fill=white, ellipse, minimum width=20pt, minimum height=10pt]
\tikzstyle{elcy}=[ellipse, minimum width=20pt, minimum height=10pt, fill=cyan!25!white]
\tikzstyle{cicy}=[fill=cyan!25!white, circle, inner sep=5pt]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        %nodes
        
        \node (a1) [cicy] at (0,0) {};
        \node (b1) [elwh, anchor=west] at ($ (a1.east) + (2,1) $) {C1R1};
        \node (b2) [elwh, anchor=west] at ($ (a1.east) + (2,-1) $) {C1R2};
        \node (c1) [draw, minimum width=40pt, anchor=west] at ($ (b1.east)!0.5!(b2.east) + (2,0) $) {\makecell[c]{coin \\ flip}};
        \node (d2) [elwh, anchor=west] at ($ (c1.east) + (2,0) $) {C2R2};
        \node (d1) [elwh] at ($ (d2) + (0,3) $) {C2R1};
        \node (d3) [elcy] at ($ (d2) + (0,-3) $) {C2R3};
        \node (e1) [elor] at ($ (d1.east) + (2,2) $)  {C3R1};
        \node (e2) [elor] at ($ (e1) + (0,-2) $)  {C3R2};
        \node (e3) [elor] at ($ (e2) + (0,-2) $) {C3R3};
        \node (e4) [elor] at ($ (e3) + (0,-2) $)  {C3R4};
        \node (e5) [elwh] at ($ (e4) + (0,-2) $) {C3R5};
        \node (e6) [elwh] at($ (e5) + (0,-2) $) {C3R6};
        
        % arrows
        
        \draw[arrowline] (a1) edge node [pos=0.5, above] {h1} (b1);
        \draw[arrowline] (a1) edge node [pos=0.5, below] {l1} (b2);
        \draw[arrowline] (b1) edge node [pos=0.5, above] {l2} (c1);
        \draw[arrowline] (b1) edge node [pos=0.5, above] {h2} (d1);
        \draw[arrowline] (c1) edge node [pos=0.5, above] {1/2} (d2);
        \draw[arrowline] (c1) edge node [pos=0.5, above] {1/2} (d3);
        \draw[arrowline] (d1) edge node [pos=0.5, above] {h3} (e1);
        \draw[arrowline] (d1) edge node [pos=0.5, above] {l3} (e2);
        \draw[arrowline] (d2) edge node [pos=0.5, above] {h4} (e3); 
        \draw[arrowline] (d2) edge node [pos=0.5, above] {h4} (e4);
        \draw[arrowline] (d3) edge node [pos=0.5, above] {h5} (e5);
        \draw[arrowline] (d3) edge node [pos=0.5, above] {l5} (e6);
        
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \node[fit=(e1)(e4), densely dashed, draw=blue, inner sep=5pt, label=above:cascade, rounded corners=5pt] {};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it's not exactly what I wanted, but it tells me a good approach to solving the problem.  a net is better than a fish.  thanks.

Comment: @ivoWelch I know, it's not a `tree` approach, but if you need some changes, let me know.

Comment: @Excelsior: I think the OP meant that your output doesn't quite match the specification that "C3R4 should be between C3R3 and C3R5, not above C3R1. (C2R1 should be higher up, too.)"

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for the comment. I changed the tree accoring to the OP's wishes

Answer (score 3):

When something is a tree, use `forest`. :)  Oval styles from Excelsior's answer. Edge label code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425271/2693).

Reading your question carefully, it seems that the tree that you produced in GraphViz is not actually how you want the tree to look. If that's the case, here's a more regular version of the tree without the crossed branch and misplaced C3R4 node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{start/.style={draw, shape=rectangle, rounded corners, align=center,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!20, content=START},
           ell/.style={ellipse, minimum width=20pt, minimum height=10pt,draw,},
           orangefill/.style={fill=orange!50!red!50!white},
           bluefill/.style={fill=cyan!30!white},
           % edge label code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425271/2693
           my edge label/.style={
    if={
      > O_= {n'}{1}
    }{
      edge label={node [midway, above] {$#1$} }
    }{
      edge label={node [midway, below,] {$#1$} }
    },
  },
  my tree/.style={where n children=0{tier=leaf}{},
    for tree={s sep=.5in,l=1in,grow=east, edge={->,thick}},
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        split option={content}{:}{content, my edge label},
      },
    }}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}my tree
      [,start [C1R2:l1,ell,tier=two,]
        [C1R1:h1,ell,
            [{coin flip}:l2,draw 
                [C2R3:1/2,ell,bluefill,tier=three
                     [C3R6:l5,ell] 
                     [C3R5:h5,ell]] 
                [C2R2:1/2,ell,name=C2R2,tier=three
                    [C3R4:l4,ell,orangefill,name=C3R4]
                    [C3R3:h4,ell,orangefill ]]] 
             [C2R1:h2,ell,tier=three
                [C3R2:l3,ell,orangefill]
                [C3R1:h3,ell,orangefill,name=C3R1]
            ]]]
\node[draw=blue,very thick,dashed,rounded corners, fit=(C3R1) (C3R4),label=above:cascade] {};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Alternate version

In case you (or others) want to see how to reproduce the GraphViz picture, here's that code too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{start/.style={draw, shape=rectangle, rounded corners, align=center,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!20, content=START},
           ell/.style={ellipse, minimum width=20pt, minimum height=10pt,draw,},
           orangefill/.style={fill=orange!50!red!50!white},
           bluefill/.style={fill=cyan!30!white},
           % edge label code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425271/2693
           my edge label/.style={
    if={
      > O_= {n'}{1}
    }{
      edge label={node [midway, above] {$#1$} }
    }{
      edge label={node [midway, below,] {$#1$} }
    },
  },
  my tree/.style={where n children=0{tier=leaf}{},
    for tree={s sep=.5in,l=1in,grow=east, edge={->,thick}},
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        split option={content}{:}{content, my edge label},
      },
    }}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}my tree
      [,start 
        [C1R2:l1,ell,tier=two,]
        [C1R1:h1,ell,
            [{coin flip}:l2,draw 
                [C2R3:1/2,ell,bluefill,tier=three
                     [C3R6:l5,ell] 
                     [C3R5:h5,ell]] 
                [C2R2:1/2,ell,name=C2R2,tier=three
                    [C3R3:h4,ell,orangefill,name=C3R3 ]]]
             [C2R1:h2,ell,tier=three
                [C3R2:l3,ell,orangefill]
                [C3R1:h3,ell,orangefill]
                [C3R4,ell,orangefill,no edge,name=C3R4]
            ]]]
\draw[->,thick] (C2R2.north) [in=180,out=60,] to node [near start,left] {$l4$} (C3R4.west);
\node[draw=blue,very thick,dashed,rounded corners, fit=(C3R3) (C3R4),label=above:cascade] {};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]